# How can I reverse a numpy transpose

Tags: python, numpy

I have the string `Luke, I am your father` that is encrypted into `LeImo tru, ufhk ayrae` with the following steps:

1: An integer number c is chosen at random. (say c=3)

2: The message is then written in a n x c array (extra characters ‘&’ might be needed if the string is too short). The dimension n is determined by the length of the string and the value of c.

3: The encrypted message is obtained from the transpose array (after removing the extra characters ‘&’)

How would I go about reversing a `numpy.transpose()` to reverse these steps so that I can decrypt  `LeImo tru, ufhk ayrae` back to `Luke, I am your father`?

Comment: With matrices, transpose is its own inverse.

Comment: "The dimension n is determined by the length of the string and the value of c." - this is insufficient information to determine *n* unambiguously. Could you please explain more how *n* is chosen?

Comment: Your asking how to crack a simple transposition cipher.  This is documented quite well.  See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: You aren't going to be able to simply reverse this if you are starting with the string with "&" removed. You will need to know where to reinsert them for this to be a simple reversal. Is that the case, or do you have the full transposed text?

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible implementation of the encryption:

```
def encrypt(s):
    # 'Luke, I am your father&&'
    char_values = [ ord(c) for c in s ]  # [76, 117, 107, 101, ...]
    array = np.array(char_values)  # np.array([76, 117, ...])
    block = array.reshape(8, 3)  # np.array([[76, 117, 107],
                                 #           [101, 44, 32], ...])
    transposed_block = block.transpose()  # [[76, 101, 73, ...], ...]
    linearized = transposed_block.reshape(1, 24)  # [76, 101, 73, ...]
    result = ''.join(chr(c) for c in linearized[0].tolist())
    # 'LeImo tru,  ufh&k ayrae&'
```

For decrypting you just need to replace the `(8, 3)` by a `(3, 8)`, the rest of the function is exactly alike.

Keep in mind that this implementation only can process a string of exactly 24 characters length.